# JLabel inside JTable's cell does not change the label's cursor

Tags: jtable, tablecellrenderer

After creating a `JTable` into which I display labels via `getTableCellRenderers`, I want to set the cursor on the labels to show a hand icon, however, no changes are shown in actual table.

I have found many solutions referring to the cursor change on an entire column, but not in the level of one label inside it.

I.e., a hyper link label inside a table cell should only show the hand icon if the cursor is actually on it, and not just inside the cell.